# Join/Look In Mysql Three Tables In One Query

Tags: php, mysql

I decided to create People You May Know System but i have accounted a problem where it seems I need to join three tables to bring relevant results.

The aim is to check in database table for possible friends one may know based on friend of my friend `(if user1 = user2 and user2 = user4 posibile user1 knows user4, user4 is a suggestion)` I have used the following code to check this and is working as to plan.

```
SELECT `friendpin` AS `possible_friend_id`
FROM `pinme`
WHERE `senderpin`
IN (
SELECT `friendpin`
FROM `pinme`
WHERE `senderpin` = $userlogged
)
AND `friendpin` NOT
IN (

SELECT `friendpin`
FROM `pinme`
WHERE `senderpin` = $userlogged
)
AND NOT `friendpin` = $userlogged
GROUP BY `possible_friend_id`
ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC
LIMIT 0 , 3
```

Thus its possible that the suggested person status in `REQUEST` table he/she has already a request pending to you but still being shown as suggested friend or in the `BLOCKED` table the suggested friend was blocked but still appear to you as suggested friend. therefore I would like to eliminate this behavior. a suggested person should not be exits either in `REQUEST` table or `BLOCKED` table.

Can anyone help me solve this?

the following are the  `REQUEST` table, `PINME` table and  `BLOCKED` table structure

```
REQUEST TABLE:
senderpin - id of the person who send request   
friendpin - receivers request id    


BLOCKED TABLE: 
user1_id - a person who block user2_id
user2_id - the blocked person by user1_id


PINME TABLE:
PINME table: the table which keep relations
structure: 1,2 2,2 | 4,8 8,4
senderpin - id of the person who send request   
friendpin - receivers request id
```

Thanks and regards

Comment: I think it may be more efficient to check before you insert them, rather than filtering those records out by making your select query more complex.

Comment: do you need the solution to get down to N depth of suggestions? your example looks like it will only bring back friends of friends. do you need to do friends of friends of friends...etc?

Comment: by the way, your database structure makes it more difficult to manage the relationships of users. I would suggest having one table called UserRelationships or something. Then have (UserId FK | DestUserId FK | Relation char(1)) where relation is a flag or blocked, friend, or request. This would help with all of these joins and cut down on the number of rows in the system.

Comment: @WhiteboardDev friend of my friend who is not my friend that's what the query is doing. in other cases the suggested friend can be a blocked person so i want to avoid the person being selected as suggested if he/she was blocked or later he/she sent request to another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you seem to need to do is join the pinme table against itself, and then against itself again to find the matches. Do a LEFT OUTER JOIN with the results of that against the blocked table and against the request table to exclude any records where there is already a blocked or request record.

Something like this:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.aPerson
FROM (SELECT friendpin AS aFriend FROM pinme WHERE senderpin = $userlogged UNION SELECT senderpin AS aFriend FROM pinme WHERE friendpin = $userlogged) a
INNER JOIN (SELECT senderpin AS aPerson, friendpin AS aFriend FROM pinme UNION SELECT senderpin AS aFriend, friendpin AS aPerson FROM pinme) b
ON a.aFriend = b.aFriend
INNER JOIN (SELECT senderpin AS aPerson, friendpin AS aFriend FROM pinme UNION SELECT senderpin AS aFriend, friendpin AS aPerson FROM pinme) c
ON b.aPerson = c.aFriend
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT user1_id AS blocked FROM blocked WHERE user2_id = $userlogged UNION SELECT user2_id AS aFriend FROM blocked WHERE user1_id = $userlogged) d
ON c.aPerson = d.blocked
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT senderpin AS blocked FROM request WHERE friendpin = $userlogged UNION SELECT friendpin AS aFriend FROM request WHERE senderpin = $userlogged) e
ON c.aPerson = e.blocked
WHERE d.blocked IS NULL
AND  e.blocked IS NULL
AND c.aPerson != $userlogged
```

EDIT - Modified suggestion

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.aPerson
FROM (SELECT senderpin AS aPerson, friendpin AS aFriend FROM pinme WHERE senderpin = $userlogged UNION SELECT senderpin AS aFriend, friendpin AS aPerson FROM pinme WHERE friendpin = $userlogged) a -- Find friends
INNER JOIN (SELECT senderpin AS aPerson, friendpin AS aFriend FROM pinme UNION SELECT senderpin AS aFriend, friendpin AS aPerson FROM pinme) b -- Find friends of friends who are not the original person
ON a.aFriend = b.aFriend AND a.aPerson != b.aFriend
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT senderpin AS aPerson, friendpin AS aFriend FROM pinme WHERE senderpin = $userlogged UNION SELECT senderpin AS aFriend, friendpin AS aPerson FROM pinme WHERE friendpin = $userlogged) c -- Find friends
ON c.aFriend = b.aPerson 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT user1_id AS blocked FROM blocked WHERE user2_id = $userlogged UNION SELECT user2_id AS aFriend FROM blocked WHERE user1_id = $userlogged) d
ON b.aPerson = d.blocked
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT senderpin AS blocked FROM request WHERE friendpin = $userlogged UNION SELECT friendpin AS aFriend FROM request WHERE senderpin = $userlogged) e
ON b.aPerson = e.blocked
WHERE d.blocked IS NULL
AND  e.blocked IS NULL
AND  c.aFriend IS NULL
AND b.aPerson != $userlogged
```

Comment: let me try it i will come back to you soon

Comment: thanks for the interest but the code didn't work is showing people who are already my friends not myfriends of myfriends. the thing is only check if the person is blocked or not or has already request.

Comment: I will have more of a play. To make it easier could you put up your table declares and a few sample records?